# Using Laravel - Php pass input value to URL

Tags: php, html, laravel

My purpose is to get the input value to action url form.

Html:

```
<form method="POST" action="/search/the/{{$request->find}}">
{{csrf_field()}}
<div id="check" class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">       
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="find" placeholder="Search">
    <button type="submit"><div id="search" class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div></button>
</div>
</form>
```

Routes:

```
Route::post('/search/the/{names}', 'maincontroller@search');
Route::get('/tfind', 'maincontroller@takefind');
```

Controller:

```
public function search($names, Request $request)
    {
        //dd($request->find);
        $names = $request->input('find');


    if(!empty($names)){
        $find = DB::table('products')
        ->select('name', 'description', 'price')
        ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $names . '%')
        ->orwhere('description', 'LIKE', '%' . $names . '%')
        ->orwhere('price', 'LIKE', '%' . $names . '%')
        ->get();    
    }

    return view('layouts.search', compact('find', 'names'));
}
public function takefind(Request $request)
{
    $names = $request->input('find');

    return view('layouts.find', compact('names'));
}
```

When I put manually the wildcard key it works (for example):

```
<form method="POST" action="/search/the/5">
```

first put number 5 in text field and press enter it works!
But I want a dynamic way for this!
My main purpose of this is to convert this URL

```
http://localhost:8000/search/the/?find=5
```

to this

```
http://localhost:8000/search/the/5
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally laravel using url query like **http://localhost:8000/search/the/?find=5**. But if you want to get url like **http://localhost:8000/search/the/5**. You should use javascript to change form action url instead. because you want to change url by input text on  text field.

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: You can use <form method="POST" action="{{route('/search/the', ['names' => 5])}}"> for first time. 

When browser finished render , you cannot can route by php code. so you should use javascript instead.

`<script>
    $(function(){
       $(".form-control").on('change',function(e){
           $("#yourFormId").attr("action","/search/the/" + $(this).val());
       });
    });
</script>`

Comment: It seems right.. but where it gets the variable in + this.val().
Something is unfinished.. can you complete the example..?

Answer (score 0):

You set `names` as named route in routes.php. So you will need to replace this

`<form method="POST" action="/search/the/5">`

with

`<form method="POST" action="{{route('/search/the', ['names' => 5])}}">`

with variable

`<form method="POST" action="{{route('/search/the', ['names' => $request->find])}}">`

Comment: Yes it works for number 5 (this is a manually way). 5 is an example I dont want this for every searching.

I want a variable instead of 5 to do that dynamically.

Comment: 5 was an example I used. You can input anything. For e.g.,
`<form method="POST" action="{{route('/search/the', ['names' => $request->find])}}">`

Comment: Yes I tryed before it shows me.

Undefined variable: request (View: C:\wamp64\www\test3\resources\views\layouts\find.blade.php)

Comment: Could you pass the variable from controller to the view? Then replace `$request->find` with your variable. I am not really sure where / how you include the form.

Comment: Yes I do that and return null.

Comment: Could you be a little more descriptive about how you are passing it? It is a little tough for me to check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109415/discussion-between-ryanicle-and-vasilis-greece).